# Are canonical links playing havoc with paging?

Tags: support

I'm cross posting this: [Canonical links and paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972815/canonical-links-and-paging)

I just did a google search for ["press the Alt button" site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=%22press+the+Alt+button%22+site:stackoverflow.com), unexpectedly it is missing the hit from [page 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033?sort=votes&page=5#sort-top) of one of the most popular questions.

Is this canonical link feature playing nicely with paging?

Comment: Does *anything* play nicely with paging? Do questions with more than 1 page of answers play nicely with... *anything*?

Comment: The amount of hoops a site that supports rich filtering and sorting needs to jump through to keep search engines happy is enough to make me a real sad panda. I just made my response permalinks route to a different area all together just so I could include it in the robots.txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely Google will index pagination of the form

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033?sort=votes&page=5#sort-top

because of this in our robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /*?
# above line, refer to http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40360
```

relevant section of page, quoted:

> **To block access to all URLs that include a question mark (?)** (more specifically, any URL that begins with your domain name, followed by any string, followed by a question mark, followed by any string):
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot
> Disallow: /*?
> ```

Comment: Fair enough, is this good? bad? on one hand the you have content that is not indexable that is valid. on the other, the fix is mega hairy.

Comment: note: globbing is not really in the robots.txt spec proper. some robots will not support it.

Comment: "answers" that are not on page 1 (that is, within the top 30 responses) are rarely useful. So no, I don't really have a problem with answers 31-500 not being indexed by Google.